# 90'/00' movie about a man/boy on a quest

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think this movie is from the early 2000. A man goes on a quest to get something for his girlfriend/wife?

The quest start with him need to defeat an old man who is a martial arts master.
After that I only know some vague details.

There are witches who 'fast travel' with candles. I also believe there is a assassin? who has killed his brothers and they follow him as ghosts.

And at some point the main protagonist runs in to pirates who capture him but after he finds out the captain is cross dressing they become his allies.

Somehow the movie title Starfall stuck with me but I can't find a movie with that name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [*Stardust*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486655/) (2007)

> The passage from this world to the fantasy kingdom of Stormhold is through a breach in a wall beside an English village. In the 1800s, a boy becomes a man when he ventures through the breach in pursuit of a fallen star, to prove his love for the village beauty. The star is no lump of rock, it's a maiden, Yvaine. Tristan, the youth, is not the only one looking for her: three witches, led by Lamia, want her heart to make them young; and, the sons of the dead king of Stormhold want her because she holds a ruby that will give one of them title to the throne. Assisting Tristan are his mother, the victim of a spell, and a cross-dressing pirate of the skies. Will Tristan win his true love?

Comment: FWIW I thought of this instantly, even if it took me a while to remember the name, and you're misremembered name cemented it for me that this is probably what you're after.

Comment: This is definitely the movie, Thank you! My version of the plot is rather different tho haha.

Comment: @ShadowTwins TBH it's been a while since I saw it but there were enough connections for me to think of it instantly so it can't be that bad!